# Matching a vector with a vector of patterns in R

Tags: r

Given a vector of URLs I want to filter these URLs and pulling out only URLs matching a set of patterns.

```r
/pages/
/econo/*
/categ/sub
```

I am currently using the `data.table` package. For matching a vector with a single pattern I use:

```r
urls[! urls %like% "/pages"]
```

However, when using multiple patterns this does not work:

```r
urls[! urls %like% c("/pages/", "/categ/sub")]
```

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `|` to separate the patterns:

```r
urls[!urls %like% paste(c("/pages/", "/categ/sub"), collapse = "|")]
```

Example:

```r
DT <- data.table(a = paste0(letters, rev(letters)))
DT[a %like% paste(c("a", "b", "c"), collapse = "|")]
```

Edit: This also works without the data.table package:

```r
vector <- paste0(letters, rev(letters))
patterns <- c("a", "b", "c")
matches <- unique(grep(paste(patterns, collapse = "|"), 
                       vector, value = TRUE))
```